# python: converting list into string, adding ',' only when '|' is not around

Tags: python, string, list

how to convert list into string, while adding ',' only when '|' is not around

example:
   list=['q0','|','q1','q0','|','#','|','#']

into printed string:  q0|q1,q0|#|#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = ['q0','|','q1','q0','|','#','|','#']
','.join(x).replace(',|', '|').replace('|,','|')
```

Had to edit because I forgot the comma on the other side, it's a bit ugly now

Alternatively, with regexp

```
re.sub(',?\|,?','|', ','.join(x))
```

Comment: I know it wasn't mentioned in the original question, but just a note; this isn't guaranteed to work for if the elements themselves contain `|` or `,`.

Comment: you'll have to do it with a for loop then, to distinguish between values, e.g. http://pastebin.com/D22a2ykk

Answer (score -2):

```
list=['q0','|','q1','q0','|','#','|','#']

strval = ' '.join(list)

strfinal = strval.replace(',','|')
```

http://www.decalage.info/en/python/print_list